# Error when calling simple Postgres procedure from .Net

Tags: .net, postgresql

I have this very simple procedure that compiles and can be successfully executed from pgAdmin:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE module.test(IN pi_data int, inout po_data int)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    SECURITY DEFINER 
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
 po_data := 11;
END;
$BODY$;
ALTER PROCEDURE module.test(int, int) OWNER TO module;
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE module.test(int, int) TO PUBLIC;
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE module.test(int, int) TO module;
```

However when I try to call it from .Net (using Npgsql library) I get the `"Npgsql.PostgresException: '42601: syntax error at end of input'"`.

```
NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder cb = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
  using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(cb.ConnectionString))
  {
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand("CALL module.test", connection))
    {
       var pin = command.Parameters.Add("pi_data", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer);
       pin.Value = 2;
       pin.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
       var pout = command.Parameters.Add("po_data", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer);
       pout.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
       pout.Value = 8;

       command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
   }
```

Any ideas where is the syntax error? I assume not on DB side since there this procedure runs fine. But the .Net code also is pretty basic with little room for error.

Comment: The parameters in the SQL string are missing. Try `CALL module.test($1,$2)` or `CALL module.test(@pi_data,@po_data)`

Comment: Yup, just figured that out. Thanks.